# Accessing a database gives me force closes

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data from a database table named `item_table`. I have a column name as `Category` which contains a value named `Pasta`. I am trying to retrieve the data using a `Where` clause, but I am getting an error called `no such column as Pasta`. Please guide me step by step. My codes and error logs as follows:

error log

```
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070): Process: com.alrimal, PID: 4070
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alrimal/com.alrimal.MenuItemsActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Pasta (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE Category=Pasta
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Pasta (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE Category=Pasta
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at com.helper.DbHelper.retrieve_item_details(DbHelper.java:158)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at com.alrimal.MenuItemsActivity.onCreate(MenuItemsActivity.java:57)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4070):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
   E/AndroidRuntime(4070):  ... 11 more
```

my Dbhelper code

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> retrieve_item_details(String category) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM item_table";
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE Category="+category;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("rowid", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("id", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("Item_Id", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("Item_Name", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("Price", cursor.getString(4));
            map.put("Currency", cursor.getString(5));
            map.put("Desc", cursor.getString(6));


            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }cursor.close();
    database.close();

    return wordList;
}
```

My activity where I call the database is as follows:

```
items=db.retrieve_item_details(getcategory);
```

Comment: Show your create statement for `item_table ` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the column name 'Category' is missing from table that table please cross check it.

Comment: I viewed it in sqlite manager..there is a column named category

Comment: ok,Then  Uy query should be int this form "SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE Category='"+category + "'";

Answer (score 0):

Run the app on a virtual device, then go to DDMS perspective, from there data/data/yourapplication/database/yourdatabasename then pull the db on the your computer and open it with the mozilla.(Note:To open sqlite database in mozilla you must have to add Sqlite manager add on.)
Now you can check your database.It helps you to resolve your issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

`Pasta` should be a string literal in `'single quotes'` to not be taken as a column name.

However, it's better to use parameters in the query. Replace literals with `?` in the SQL and supply the values in the bind arguments to a query function:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE Category=?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { category });
```